# How can I update cookies after having it set on the header in a Perl CGI program?

Tags: perl, cookies

I have cookies set when the user log in to the application. Yet I need to modify that when the user updates his profile. Can anyone tell me how to update an existing cookies?
Thanks in advance.(I'm using perl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[CGI::Cookie](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/CGI::Cookie) is all you need.

To get the cookies sent to your application:

```
my %cookies = CGI::Cookie->fetch;
my $foo = $cookies{foo}->value;
```

If you're using CGI.pm to generate your headers, then sending a `Set-Cookie` header just requires passing in the `CGI::Cookie` object:

```
my $q = CGI->new;
print $q->header( -cookie => $foo );
```

Otherwise, use whatever header-manipulation interface is provided by the web application framework you are using.

Comment: when i tried that, I get that:
Set-Cookie: test.jpg Date: Thu, 11 Feb 2010 18:44:24 GMT Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 printed on the page.

I can't change with the header. So I'm having it printed it on the page, I want a way to modify the cookies without printing it.

Comment: If you want to modify a cookie, you have to set a Cookie header. If something else is setting your header and you can't modify it, you need to seriously rethink your application architecture. The only other way to change a cookie is to do it client-side in Javascript.

Comment: Friedo, when you say I can do that using javascript, what do you mean?
Can you give me a good example please?

Comment: @zeina: emit into your html something like `<script>document.cookie='foo=bar; expires=Thu, 11 Feb 2010 08:00:00 UTC; path=/'</script>`

Comment: Thanks Guys, this link helped me:
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html
Thanks Friedo for your suggestion.